# IHttpActionResult return standards

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple Web API, which reads data from an XML file and returns it as a JSON object.

If the XML file is found and properly read then, I return `Ok(jsonObject)`, which is fine in my opinion. ***But*** what should I return along with the exception message in case an exception occurs?

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(string timestamp)
{

    try
    {
        //Read XML
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\myfile.xml");

        //Convert XML data into JSON string
        string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xDoc);
        JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonStr);

        return Ok(json);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Ok(ex.Message.ToString()); 
        //return NotFound(); //I CANNOT RETURN EXCEPTION MESSAGE WITH NotFound()
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:** Above is the sample code but in my actual code, there are more than one XML file, which are read. In addition to the read operation, there are some XML operations too so there I would really like to know the reason of exception.

Comment: Well, an exception is NOT Ok(). So return an error, like `UnprocessableEntity()`. Or do nothing and let ASP.net return a 500 internal server error. Might be the best choice here.

Comment: I'd have a couple of checks.  If the file doesn't exist, return a 404.  If some exception is thrown during processing just let it go (remove the try/catch) and it will get converted to a 500.

Comment: @bommelding: I actually want to return the exception message too so that the correct reason of failure is found.

Comment: @Fran: Actually there are more than one XML file (I have shown just one for example) so, I would like to know which file was missing exactly through the exception message.

Comment: The you should provide [mcve] that represents the actual problem, as answers would be based on what was presented in the question.

Comment: @skm If that's the case then you should be logging the exceptions rather than returning them. As I mentioned in my answer, it's never a good idea to return stack traces or too much info in general to the consumers about your servers implementation. Logging the exceptions will make them more available to you (you don't have to call the API yourself to see errors being thrown), and keeps the error messages hidden from the consumer.

Comment: @EricMagers: Yes, I think that logging execptions will be a better way in this case. Is there any way to manage logging in C# becasue I do not want to increase the size of a file with logging information of one year(s).

Comment: @skm There are many ways to manage logging. All the answers to this question are completely dependent on what framework you're working with (there are many different ways). I'd suggest doing a google search for logging in whatever version of ASP.Net you're using and you'll find a lot of examples.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the exception and how much information you want to give in your responses. If it is the case that the XML file cannot be found, I'd say returning the NotFound() result without any kind of message is sufficient. This returns a 404 - Not Found HTTP response which indicates the resource requested was not found.

If there are some other exceptions that may pop up, then a 500 response would probably be sufficient. This will allow you to return the exception message and stack trace, but keep in mind that the response content will usually be omitted (for good reason) when running in a not-development environment. You don't want to give the consumers of your API too much information on the internal workings of your server.

Overall, I'd say read up on HTTP status codes and decide which ones best fit the scenarios you're trying to handle. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes